# Can you proof why casting is important when I deference a void pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void

Why is necessary do casting when I dereference a void pointer?

I have this example:

```
int x;
void* px = &x;
*px = 9;
```

Can you proof why this don't work?

Comment: Because the compiler has no idea which type to store at that location?  Types have different sizes and representations in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a `void` pointer points to an I'm-not-sure-what-type-of-object.

By definition, when you use the unary `*` operator to access the object pointed to by a pointer, you must know (well, the compiler must know) what the type of the object is.

So we have just proved that we cannot directly dereference a `void` pointer using `*`; we must always explicitly cast the `void` pointer to some actual object pointer type first.

Now, in many people's minds, the "obvious" answer to "what type does/should a 'generic' pointer point to?" is "`char`".  And, once upon a time, before the `void` type had been invented, character pointers were routinely used as "generic" pointers.  So some compilers (including, notably, gcc) extend things a bit and let you do more (such as pointer arithmetic) with a `void` pointer than the standard requires.

So that *might* explain how code like that in your question might be able to "work".  (In your case, though, since the pointed-to type was actually `int`, not `char`, if it "worked" it was only because you were on a little-endian machine.)

...And with that said, I find that the code in your question does *not* work for me, not even under gcc.  It first gives me a non-fatal warning:

> warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer

But then it changes its mind and decides this is an error instead:

> error: invalid use of void expression

A second compiler I tried said something similar:

> error: incomplete type 'void' is not assignable

---

Addendum: To say a little more about *why* the pointed-to type is reuired when you dereference a pointer:

When you access a pointer using `*`, the compiler is going to emit code to fetch from (or maybe store to) the pointed-to location.  But the compiler is going to have to emit code that accesses a certain number of bytes, and in many cases it may matter how those byte(s) are interpreted.  Both the number and the interpretation of the bytes is determined by the type (that's what types are *for*), which is precisely why an actual, non-`void` type is required.

One of the best ways I know of appreciating this requirement is to consider code like

```
*p + 1
```

or, even better

```
*p += 1
```

If `p` points to a `char`, the compiler is probably going to emit some kind of an `addb` ("add byte") instruction.
If `p` points to an `int`, the compiler is going to emit an ordinary `add` instruction.
If `p` points to a `float` or `double`, the compiler is going to emit a floating-point addition instruction.  And so on.

But if `p` is a `void *`, the compiler has no idea what to do.  It complains (in the form of an error message) not just because the C standard says you can't dereference a `void` pointer, but more importantly, because the compiler simply doesn't know what to do with your code.

Answer (score 2):

In short:

The target of an assignment expression must be a *modifiable lvalue*, which cannot be a `void` expression.  This is because the `void` type does not represent *any* values - it denotes an *absence* of a value.  You cannot create an object of type `void`.

If the expression `px` has type `void *`, then the expression `*px` has type `void`.  Attempting to assign to `*px` is a *constraint violation* and the compiler is required to yell at you for it.

If you want to assign a new value to `x` through `px`, then you *have* to cast `px` to an `int *` before dereferencing:

```
*((int *)px) = 5;
```

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.2.5 Types**
> ...
> 19 The **`void`** type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that
> cannot be completed.
> ...
> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> 1 An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than **`void`**) that potentially
> designates an object<sup>;64)</sup> if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the
> behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is
> specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. A *modifiable lvalue* is an lvalue that
> does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
> recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.
> ...
> **6.3.2.2 void**
> 1 The (nonexistent) value of a **`void`** expression (an expression that has type **`void`**) shall not
> be used in any way, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to **`void`**) shall not be
> applied to such an expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void
> expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression is evaluated for its
> side effects.)
> ...
> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> 1 A pointer to **`void`** may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
> any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall
> compare equal to the original pointer.
> ...
> **6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**
> ...
> 4 The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is
> a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the
> object. If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’, the result has type ‘‘*type*’’. If an
> invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is
> undefined.<sup>102)</sup>
> ...
> **6.5.16 Assignment operators**
> ...
> Constraints
> 2 An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, dereferencing a void pointer violates the wording of [**6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**, paragraph 4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4):

> The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. If the operand has type ''pointer to type'', the result has type ''type''. If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined.

Since a pointer to void has no "type" - it can't be dereferenced.  Note that this is beyond  undefined behavior - it is a violation of the C language standard.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't work because it violates a rule in the ISO C standard which requires a diagnostic, and (I'm guessing) your compiler is treating that as a fatal situation.

According to ISO C99, as well as the C11 Draft (n1548), the only constraint on the use of the `*` dereferencing operator is "[t]he operand of the unary `*`operator shall have pointer type." [6.5.3.2¶2, n1548]    The code we have here meets that constraint, and has no syntax error. Therefore no diagnostic is required for the use of the `*` operator.

However, what is the meaning of the `*` operator applied to a `void *` pointer?

> "The unary `*` operator denotes indirection.  If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue  designating the object. If  the operand  has  type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has  type ‘‘type’’. [6.5.3.2¶4, n1548]

The type `void` is neither a function nor an object type, so the middle sentence, which talks about producing a function or object designator, is not applicable to our case. The last sentence quoted above **is** applicable; it gives a requirement that an expression which dereferences a `void *` has `void` type.

Thus `*px = 9;` runs aground because it's assigning an `int` value to a `void` expression.  An assignment requires an lvalue expression of object type; `void` is not an object type and the expression is certainly not an lvalue. The exact wording of the constraint is: "An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand." [6.5.16¶2, n1548] Violation of this constraint requires a diagnostic.

It appears from my perhaps naive reading of the standard that the expression `*px` *as such* is valid; only no attempt must be made to extract a result from it, or use it as the target of an assignment. If that is true, it could be used as an expression statement whose value is discarded: `if (foo()) { *px; }`, and it could be redundantly cast to `void` also: `(void) *px`.  These apparently pointless situations might be somehow exploited by, or at least arise in, certain kinds of macros.

For instance, if we want to be sure that the argument of some macro is a pointer we can take advantage of the constraint that `*` requires a pointer operand:

```
#define MAC(NUM, PTR) ( ...  (void) *(PTR) ...)
```

I.e. somewhere in the macro we dereference the pointer and throw away the result, which will diagnose if `PTR` isn't a pointer. It looks like ISO C allows this usage even if `PTR` is a `void *`, which is arguably useful.

Comment: Re “The type `void` is neither a function nor an object type”: `void` is an object type. Per C 2018 6.2.5 19, “it is an incomplete object type…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah good point; basically this discussion applies to all incomplete object types. It seems `*ptr` *per se* is fine if `ptr` is incomplete (including `void`), as long as there is no attempt to use the value, or assign to it.